# ASP.NET Upload file via ajax returns error everytime

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to do an ASP.NET file upload via ajax. I have this ajax call in place:

```
 $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: '/Home/Upload',
                                            data: formData,
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            contentType: false,
                                            processData: false,
                                            success: function (response) {
                                                alert('success!!');
                                                $("#" + id).attr('disabled', false);
                                            },
                                            error: function (error) {
                                                alert("errror");
                                            }
                                        });
```

and this is my .NET code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Upload()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"),
                                               Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

        }
```

When I goto the folder, I can see its been uploaded, but for some reason the ajax returns the alert error, please help.

Comment: You need to define [WebMethod] attribute along with [HttpPost].

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to return something. With out returninging it always gives error.

```
 [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult AsyncUpload()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"),
                                           Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return Json(new { success = true },
            "text/plain");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a boolean value from server to client, to understand if the process finished correctly or not.

**C#:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Upload() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) {
            // your stuff
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

** JS: **

```
$.ajax({
    // your options
    success: function (response) {
        if (response) {
            alert('success!!');
            $("#" + id).attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            alert("an errror occurred");
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```